# GCLOUD_CONFIG Google Standard envoirement

Tags: java, google-app-engine

It was not clear in the document

**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <projectId>myProjectId</projectId>
    <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**

How to set:
Note: GCLOUD_CONFIG is a special version for autogenerating an App Engine version. Change this field to specify a specific version name.

Following this sample from google app engine

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

Answer (score 0):

Inside your App Engine application you can have multiple services, and each service can have multiple versions too.

[Services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#services) can be used to break down your application into smaller logical components. [Versions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#versions) can be used to keep track of the changes that have been made to a specific service, which make it easier to go back to previous states in case a rollback is needed.

The  tag will set a version name to the version you are going to deploy. If you leave it empty it will use a timestamp by default.